# After completion of inapp purchase billingclient.querypurchase().getPurchaseList() is returning null

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am testing in app purchases for my app using internal testers I was able to buy the product and acknowledge the purchase but when I use queryPurchases(). getPurchasesList ()  it is returning null.please help

Answer (score 1):

billingclient.querypurchase().getPurchaseList() this only works on the version 2.x when responseCode is ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED. You should check their sample.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt#L135